# как выдвинуть блок справа налево

Tags: html, css

```css
body, html, h1, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.circlewrap {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px grey;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px grey;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
            justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
.circlewrap .text {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .text {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 580px);
    text-align: right;
  }
}
.circlewrap .text h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .text h1 {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
.circlewrap .text p {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .text p {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
.circlewrap .circle {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 53px);
  }
}
.circlewrap .circle .c-cont {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 53px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.circlewrap .circle .c-cont img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .circle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .circle:hover + .h-wrap {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
            filter: opacity(1);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .h-wrap:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-animation-name: bordW;
            animation-name: bordW;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    width: 600px;
  }
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .h-wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .h-wrap .hidden {
    margin-left: 120px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.circlewrap .h-wrap .hidden p {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap .h-wrap .hidden p {
    -webkit-animation-name: textQ;
            animation-name: textQ;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-duration: 2s;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes textQ {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
            filter: opacity(0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
            filter: opacity(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0.5);
            filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
            filter: opacity(1);
  }
}

@keyframes textQ {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
            filter: opacity(0);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0);
            filter: opacity(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0.5);
            filter: opacity(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
            filter: opacity(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bordW {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
@keyframes bordW {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px grey;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px grey;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .text {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .text {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% + 66px);
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .text h1 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .text h1 {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .text p {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .text p {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .circle {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .circle {
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 53px);
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .circle .c-cont {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #c2c2c2;
  border-radius: 53px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.circlewrap-reverse .circle .c-cont img {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .circle:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .circle:hover + .h-wrap {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
    -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
            filter: opacity(1);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #f00;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-animation-name: bordW;
            animation-name: bordW;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    width: 600px;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
    z-index: 10;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap .hidden {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap .hidden {
    margin-left: 120px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap .hidden p {
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 6px;
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  .circlewrap-reverse .h-wrap .hidden p {
    -webkit-animation-name: textQ;
            animation-name: textQ;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-duration: 2s;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="circlewrap">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Анализ конкурентной среды</h1>
                <p>Проводится детальный анализ ТОПА по продвигаемым запросам и сайтам конкурентов</p>
            </div>
            <div class="circle">
                <div class="c-cont"><img src="img/x1.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="h-wrap">
                <div class="hidden">
                    <p>На данном этапе SEO специалисты анализируют сайт конкурентов по продвигаемым запросам находящимся в ТОПЕ поисковых систем. После чего составляется план работ по продвижению.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="circlewrap-reverse">
            <div class="h-wrap">
                <div class="hidden">
                    <p>На данном этапе SEO специалисты анализируют сайт конкурентов по продвигаемым запросам находящимся в ТОПЕ поисковых систем. После чего составляется план работ по продвижению.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle">
                <div class="c-cont"><img src="img/x1.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Анализ конкурентной среды</h1>
                <p>Проводится детальный анализ ТОПА по продвигаемым запросам и сайтам конкурентов</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

есть два блока. первый работает нормально, но при попытке сделать тоже самое со вторым - выходят какие-то косяки. нужно чтобы доп инфа выезжала справа налево, но выходит с точностью наоборот. row-reverse не помогает. может я смотрю где не там? PS: пример надо смотреть в разрешении от 1170px или не будет эффектов никаких вообще

Comment: Замените `left: calc(50% - 50px);` на `right: calc(50% - 50px);`

Comment: спасибо получилось все)))